# How to get valid Google ID token after it expires in 1 hour

Tags: android, authentication, kotlin, single-sign-on, google-signin

I've followed the guides on https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in and I can get the Google ID token of the signed in user after the user signed in. But token will expires in 1 hour.

How can I refresh a valid Google ID token after the old one expires, without bothering user to manually sign in again and again? I have tried using silent sign-in when token expires. But it doesn't seem to work. Is there any way to get a valid Google ID token? Thanks in advance!!

For first time signing in,

```
private fun handleSignInResult(completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
    try {
        val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
        val idToken = account!!.idToken
        CheckDB(this, db).execute()
    } catch (e: ApiException) {
        Log.e("TAG","signInResult:failed code=" + e.statusCode)
    }
}
```

when token expires, I am using silent signin

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)
    if(account!=null) {
        sign_in_button.visibility = GONE
        mGoogleSignInClient!!.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(this, object : OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>{
            override fun onComplete(p0: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
                val account = p0.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                CheckDB(this@SignInActivity, db).execute()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your user is signed in (the first and only time), use the obtained token to authenticate to your own backend server. No need to re-signin at google's.
Details here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth

Comment: @H Ystad, the Google ID token expires after  1 hour. Servers responds with 401 unauthorized

Comment: Yes, Google's window is 1 hour. But **you** don't have to timeout that quick. Once you have the token from Google, complete the authorization on your own server (as described on the link I posted), and stay authorized **as long as you like**. Here's how the Google documentation puts it:

_After you have verified the token, check if the user is already in your user database. If so, establish an authenticated session for the user. If the user isn't yet in your user database, create a new user record from the information in the ID token payload, and establish a session for the user._

Comment: @H Ystad   what if our server token valid for 4 hours and after 4 hours if user interact with application he cannot access the protected routes and at that time both Google token and server token gets expired

Comment: A problem, granted. But then maybe you should just implement something to have your own token renewed automatically, since the Google one poses problems? (I realize this is not helping with the original question, but I do believe that Google's 1-hour short window is such for a reason ...)

Answer (score 0):

By default, access tokens have a validity of 1 hour, which appears to be sufficient for authorizing the retrieval of a signed-in user's data. Once the token has been verified with the backend server, it is imperative to establish a session for the user on the backend. There is no necessity to repeatedly fetch the access token each time a user enters the application after logging in. The primary purpose of the access token is to validate the user with the Google server.